# Why AlarmManager doesn't respond?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

[image]I have created a WorkManager class for setting a Notification using AlarmManager. I'm getting the information about next event from local database and set an AlarmManager. When I put my code into RxJava's subscribe method it works fine, but when I decided to create setAlarm() method an put the code which is responsible for setting an Alarm it doesn't work. Here is the code which I wrote and Logcat output(I replaced AlarmManager.set() with System.currentTimeInMillis()) for testing purposes, but It' doesn't work. Which means it won't work in necessary time. So what can be wrong?

```
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import org.fursa.spacex.AppDelegate
import org.fursa.spacex.utils.const.ApiConst.MISSION_DETAIL
import org.fursa.spacex.utils.const.ApiConst.MISSION_NAME
import org.fursa.spacex.api.ApiRequest
import org.fursa.spacex.db.Launch
import org.fursa.spacex.utils.formatDate
import org.fursa.spacex.utils.toLaunch
import java.util.*
import javax.inject.Inject

class AlarmSetterWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    init {
        AppDelegate.injector.inject(this)
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager

    @Inject
    lateinit var apiRequest: ApiRequest

    @Inject
    lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences

    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        disposable.add(apiRequest.getNextKnownLaunch()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map { launchResponse -> toLaunch(launchResponse) }
            .subscribe({
                launch -> setAlarm(launch)
            }, {
                Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", it.localizedMessage)
            }))
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun setAlarm(launch: Launch) {

        val rightBeforeKey = preferences.getBoolean("just_before_key", false)
        val dayBeforeKey = preferences.getBoolean("just_before_key", false)
        val minutesBeforeKey = preferences.getInt("notification_padding", 0)

        Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Right before key: $rightBeforeKey")
        Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Day before key: $dayBeforeKey")
        Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Minutes before key: $minutesBeforeKey")


        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.apply { timeInMillis = launch.timestamp * 1000 }

        if(rightBeforeKey) {
            val alarmIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_NAME, launch.title)
            alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_DETAIL, "Is launching right now!")

            Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Right before set at: ${formatDate(calendar.timeInMillis)}")
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        }

        if(dayBeforeKey) {
            val alarmIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_NAME, launch.title)
            alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_DETAIL, "Is launching tomorrow!")

            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)
            Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Day before set at: ${formatDate(calendar.timeInMillis)}")
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        }

        if(minutesBeforeKey > 0) {
            val alarmIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_NAME, launch.title)
            alarmIntent.putExtra(MISSION_DETAIL, "Is launching in $minutesBeforeKey minutes!")

            calendar.apply { timeInMillis = launch.timestamp * 1000 }
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -minutesBeforeKey)
            Log.d("Spacex/Alarm", "Minutes before set at: ${formatDate(calendar.timeInMillis)}")
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        }

    }

    override fun onStopped() {
        super.onStopped()
        disposable.clear()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code as a start. Nobody is going to comprehend what is written here.
You have to show how you create a notification channel and how your BroadcastReceiver looks like and your manifest.

For API Level >= 26 you have to create a notification channel.

Try to create an empty project just to test how AlarmManager works.

Comment: My NotificationManger class which is responsible for Notification and Notification channels works perfect and sends Notitication to Notification bar, but something wrong with AlarmManager.

Comment: Please add your manifest, your BoradcastReceiver and the function where you create the NotificationChannel and post Notifications.
For RTC_Wakeup = Sytem.currentTimeMillis + ms you want to fire the alarm in the furure.

Also Android doesnt really fire the Alarm when you say you want to fire it. For example if you say the Alarm fires in 20 seconds. It will fire in 20s + whatever time Android thinks it is ok to fire your alarm